# How do I pass a JSON array to an Angular2 template with @Input from a ASP.NET MVC View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular-components

I'm new to Angular2 and have many questions.

I have some controllers that I wrote in AngularJS that I now want to convert to Angular2 components.

I would like to pass JSON data to the component and use in the template. In AngularJS I used ng-init to do this.

I have tried initialising the component in the ASP.NET MVC view with:

```
<review [reviewJson]="@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.CustomerReviews)"></review>
```

The component looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'review',
    template: `
        <div id="reviews-wrapper" class="row">
            <div class="item col-sm-4 col-xs-6" *ngFor="let review of reviewJson">
                <div class="review-card">
                    <div class="review-image"><img [src]="review.Image"/></div>
                    <div class="review-name">review.Name</div>
                    <div class="review-text">review.Text</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    providers: []
})

export class ReviewComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() reviewJson: any;  

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.reviewJson);
    }
}
```

The app.module file where I declare the review component looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { ReviewComponent } from './review.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ReviewComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [ReviewComponent],
    providers: [
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The console.log(this.reviewJson) is showing undefined when I load the page so obviously I'm doing something completely wrong.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Share the ts file where you are using `review` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly bind the `MVC` models into the angular template - fetch the data as JSON using  `service` and then bind the value to it's `@Input` decorator

Hope this helps - happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks, I did think I might be approaching this the wrong way. I liked how I had it setup with building the models in an MVC controller but it sounds like I am going to have to fetch the data in an Angular service.

Comment: Yep you need you access your controller from the angular service and return the data from the `controller` as `JsonResult` - check this link - [https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4]

Comment: I wrote an Angular2 service to get the JSON data from Web API as suggested and it worked. The most difficult thing to understand was that it was returning an observable which I had to subscribe to so I could put the data in a variable in my component.

Comment: Great that will be your first learning curve in angular - `Observables` are **awesome** check some `rxjs` libraries that might help you more in understanding -  Check this link [https://angular.io/guide/rx-library]